# Can't access my service in a remote Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I've been looking for a similar question for a while but I haven't found one. I have a remote Kubernetes cluster with the architecture of one master and two workers. The versions installed are as following:
Kubernetes: 1.15.1-0
Docker: 18.09.1-3.el7
I'm trying to deploy & expose a JAR file of Spring project that has one REST endpoint.

Deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microservices-deployment
  labels:
    app: microservices-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      name: microservices-deployment
      labels:
        app: microservices-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: microservices-deployment
          image: **my_repo**/*repo_name*:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8085
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservices-deployment
```

service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: microservices-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: microservices-deployment
  ports:
    - port: 8085
      targetPort: 8085
  type: NodePort
```

my application.properties:

```
server.port=8085
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/microservices.jar microservices.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "microservices.jar"]
```

It looks like my pods are ready and everything looks good, but I can't access the service I exposed even from the master's terminal.
Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE***

I'm able to telnet from my master to port 30000 on my nodes (after I specified 30000 as my NodePort), as well as telnet to my pods on port 8085. When I'm trying to telnet from the master to any other port in the nodes\pods I get refuse, so I think that's a good start. Still, I'm unable to access the rest endpoint I specified although it is working on Docker locally:
docker run -p 8085:8085 *IMAGE_NAME*

Comment: Can you try port-forward or try to access the pod ip and port from another pod in the cluster. Did you use NodeIP: NodePort to access it?

Comment: I tried using nodeIP:notePORT. Didn't help.
I'll try the port-forward

Comment: @YaakovShami have you tried to build the image and run it on local docker? Because you did everything correct on deployment and services. ? My feeling is there must me an issue with you code.

Comment: Check which node the pod got scheduled(kubectl get pods -o wide) and use that nodes IP

Comment: @DashrathMundkar yes, it's working if I specify the port (-p 8085:8085)

Comment: @YaakovShami could you use something like this  ```protocol: TCP``` and ```targetPort: 8085-tcp``` to Service

Comment: @DashrathMundkar Still not change. Please see my update in the question, that might help.

Comment: When you check node ip (`kubectl get nodes -o wide`) and try to check it using <node_ip_:<node_port> does it work? Is there any firewall that might block the connection? Does it work when you try to access it from worker nodes? What is the error message?

Comment: @KFC_ yes it does! when trying to access it from the worker itself (from 127.0.0.1 only, from localhost it doesn't work). How can I expose the service two load balance between my two workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a network problem. Accessing the endpoint from one of the workers did the trick. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

You defined  that :

```
 - port: 8085
   targetPort: 8085
```

For information : `targetPort` is the port used by your containerized application  and `port` is the port of the Cluster IP (internal cluster IP).
But you didn't define a value for `nodePort`, it means that [K8s will allocate it for you](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) :

> If you set the type field to `NodePort`, the Kubernetes control plane
> allocates a port from a range specified by --service-node-port-range
> flag (default: 30000-32767).

But you can also specify that port :

> If you want a specific port number, you can specify a value in the
> nodePort field. The control plane will either allocate you that port
> or report that the API transaction failed. This means that you need to
> take care of possible port collisions yourself. You also have to use a
> valid port number, one that's inside the range configured for NodePort
> use.

Whatever, you can get/check the value of the `nodePort` chosen by K8s (or that you chose) via `kubectl -n YOUR_NAMESPACE describe service YOUR_SERVICE`.
And in a general way you should abuse of the `describe` subcommand to diagnostic/debug a K8s deployment.

Then from any node in the cluster or from the external of that (since the port is of type `nodePort`), request any node of the cluster on the allocated port (the generated or not) and you should be able to request your service from the cluster nodes.

If you want to define yourself that external port, does that explicitly
(beware : `nodePort` has to be unique inside the cluster) such as :

```
ports:
  - port: 8085
    targetPort: 8085
    nodePort: 8085
```

In that way, every cluster nodes will expose the service on the 8085 port.

Comment: Didn't help. I specified:
nodePort:30000
And tried to connect to one of the nodes, but it didn't work..

Comment: How do you know that the allocated node port is 300000 ? Have you retrieved the information with `kubectl describe service  microservices-service` ?

Comment: Yes, this is the output:
NodePort:     <unset>  30000/TCP